# What are the difference between "details" and "information"?

Tags: differences

I am confused of how to use "details" and "information" and their difference.

To better understand for both readers and me, please put these factors in the appropriate category ("details" and "information"):

- time (1PM)
- date (12 Jan 2015)
- location (Heaven)
- reason (birthday party)

Comment: Details are information of a specific kind so I'm not clear what you're trying to differentiate here.

Comment: This question may be a good candidate for our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). The short answer is that *details* are *particular* pieces of information. I may say *I am hosting parties this month*; if you ask for details, I may respond *I am hosting a Christmas party on the 19th and a New Year's Eve party*. If you ask for details about the latter, I would provide the time, location, menu, and so on. If you asked about the menu, I might list the canapes and spirits to be offered. And so on.

Answer (score 5):

*Details* are **a kind of** *information*.

They contrast with *summary* or *overview* information in that they provide supplemental information not necessary for a general understanding of the matter.

Dividing information into a summary and details is not the only possible division, nor in many circumstances the most appropriate. For example, sometimes details can be crucial for acting upon a piece information (for example, the exact time of an army's attack), and some summary information may be irrelevant in a particular circumstance.

Trying to divine the context of your question, I suspect that these are headings in some computer software, maybe a scheduler or calendar. I also suspect that the heading *information* is being used (somewhat erroneously) to mean summary information.

If this is the case (more context would be helpful), then you need to decide, for the information provided, what would serve as a summary for those glancing at the schedule, and what can be somewhat hidden as a detail for the truly curious.

This is a property not of the various kinds of information themselves, but the use to which you expect them to be put in your particular case. If your scheduler is for the owner of a nightclub, the summary may be the date and time, the rest being details; if for a provider of party requisites, the date and reason may be the most appropriate summary; if for a social calendar, the date and reason; and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Information's content just gives a bit of what happens or what's going to happen. For example:

> There will be an earthquake drill.

Details consist of more specific information about the event. For example:

> There will be an earthquake drill at XYZ
>   University from 1 to 5 in the afternoon on September 1, 2016.